# python find elemet form array in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file (the prefix could be any string ) :

```
prefix,path
pref1,path1
pref2,path2
```

and files :

```
pref1_file.txt
pref2_file.txt
pref3_file.txt
```

I want to get the path of a file based on his prefix

result for this example :

```
pref1_file.txt : path1
pref2_file.txt : path2
pref3_file.txt : path_not_found
```

Here is my code :

```
dirName = 'C:\\Users\\TEST\\Desktop\\Test'

# get all  files in all folders
listOfFiles = list()

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dirName):
    listOfFiles += [os.path.join(dirpath, file) for file in filenames]

df = pd.read_csv(dir_path + 'file.csv')

for elem in listOfFiles:
    file_name = os.path.basename(elem)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if file_name.startswith(row['prefix']):
            print(file_name + ":" + row['mask'])
        else:
            print(file_name + ":" + "path_not_found")
```

it's work but without else conditon (i need to display "path_not_found" if the prefix is not found in the csv file)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dirName = 'C:\\Users\\TEST\\Desktop\\Test'

# get all  files in all folders
listOfFiles = list()

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dirName):
    listOfFiles += [os.path.join(dirpath, file) for file in filenames]

df = pd.read_csv(dir_path + 'file.csv')

for elem in listOfFiles:
    file_name = os.path.basename(elem)
    df_prefix = df[df['prefix'].apply(lambda x: file_name.startswith(x))]
    if df_prefix.size > 0:
       print( df_prefix['prefix'].loc[0] + ":" + file_name)
    else:
       print(file_name + ": Not found")
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable

Comment: Thanks @Henry, but i get this error when i run your solution : ` TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not Series`  on this line  `df_prefix = df[lambda df: file_name.startswith(df['prefix'])]`

Comment: Try the edited version. It's hard to do without the data.

Comment: KeyError: 0 in `print(df_prefix['prefix'].loc[0] + ":" + file_name)` . listOfFiles contains only paths of all files, example : ['C:\\Users\\TEST\\Desktop\\Test\\Folder1\\pref1_file.txt', 'C:\\Users\\TEST\\Desktop\\Test\\Folder2\\pref2_file.txt', .. ]

Comment: Print out df_prefix and inside of the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
dict(zip(files, pd.Series(files).str.split('_').str[0].map(df1.set_index('prefix')['path']).fillna('path_not_found')))
```

**Output**

```
{'pref1_file.txt': 'path1',
 'pref2_file.txt': 'path2',
 'pref3_file.txt': 'path_not_found'}
```

Here, `files` is `listOfFiles` in your data

**Explanation**

- Convert `files` to `pd.Series`
- Split by `_` and take the first part
- Use pandas `map` to get the `path`
- Convert to `dict`

Answer (score 1):

To complete @Henry's solution:

```
df_prefix = df[df['prefix'].apply(lambda x: file_name.startswith(x))]
if df_prefix.size > 0:
     print(file_name + " : " + df_prefix['path'].iloc[0])
else:
     print(file_name + ": path_not_found")
```